# jQuery Autocomplete search anywhere in string for matches

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having problems getting to work the code I found as example on the jQuery website for autocomplete > http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#example-1  I am able to see my results in the autocomplete input control when I execute the following....

Here is fetchResponse

```
var cachedResult = null;
function fetchResponse(callback) {
    if (cachedResult) {
        alert("In cachedResult!");
        callback(cachedResult);
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "FacilitiesAsync",
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        data: 'sourceDb=myDb',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
            // call autocomplete callback method with results
            alert("Second");
            var cachedResult = $.map(json, function (name) {
                return {
                    label: name.label,
                    value: name.value
                };
            });
            alert("Third");                
            callback(cachedResult);
        },
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#autocomplete").text(textStatus + ', ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            alert("First");
            fetchResponse(function (result) {
                response(result);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

However, when I try and implement the functionality seen in the example from the jQuery website I don't get any results at all.  I was hoping to filter my results so the user can type any word in the text box and the list is filtered, not just searched at the beginning, but I am not sure the RegEx for that either.

UPDATED CODE:  I see results in the input control but they are never filtered and I get an error in Firefox console that 'elems' is undefined.  I know this has to do with me passing response(result) into the grep function but I don't know how to fix it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            fetchResponse(function (result) {
                var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                response($.grep(response(result), function (item) {
                    return response(matcher.test(item.label));
                }));                                        
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I am calling this inside fetchedResponse because I need to get the data first and this works.  I see data in the input control when I don't try and filter it.

Please forgive me, I am still a newby to jQuery.

Comment: what is `fetchResponse` can you provide code?

Comment: Code has been updated

Answer (score 0):

The code needs to be modified as follows,

**js**

```
function fetchResponse(callback) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      /*assuming this is result from ajax*/
      var tags = ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"];
      callback(tags);
    },2000);
}

$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        fetchResponse(function (result) {
            var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
            response($.grep(result, function (item) {
                return matcher.test(item);
            }));
        });
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c5YMF/1